# Unable to find packages for RHEL 6.8

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, python3

I have RHEL 6.8 and I am trying to install following packages and failing because they are not available via any repos. Your vast knowledge can probably help me.

```
httpd 2.2
httpd-devel for 2.2
python 3.5,
python3.5 libs
python3.5 devel
python3.5
```

I installed them on CentOS 7 without any problem but RHEL 6.8, I just couldn't find them.

Comment: You can do # yum list > yumlist and cat yumlist | grep httpd or python.

Comment: See if they are available first by using `yum search python3` for example. You may not have the names correct. If they are not, you'll have to look into additional repositories (non-official) to add to your /etc/yum.repos.d/

Answer (score 0):

2.2 is the standard version in RHEL6, so you're just looking for `httpd` and `httpd-devel` there. Python 3.5 might be too new, or take a look at [RedHat Software Collections for EL6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/2.3_Release_Notes/chap-RHSCL.html#sect-RHSCL-Changes-python), which includes Python 3.5.1.